# How do you say a Czech Republic habitant in feminine and masculine form?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre, toponymes

I know that the person living in Czech Republic in France would be tchèque, but I'm not sure what would be the difference of that word between masculine and feminine.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between feminine and masculine form. Only the context, and in particular pronouns used with the noun or adjective, will characterize the gender of the person you're referring to (i.e "Elle est tchèque, il est tchèque", or "Une Tchèque, un Tchèque").

Note that this is not particular to Czechs, it's a rule that applies to most nationalities whose french designation end in "-e" in the masculine form, i.e Russian (un/une Russe), Bulgarian (un/une Bulgare), Slovakian (un/une Slovaque) etc. Swiss [being the only exception](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Suissesse).

Comment: not true for Swiss (un Suisse, une Suissesse) => une suisse is only used as adjective (i.e. une montre suisse)

Comment: @PaulLemarchand c'est tout à fait juste, merci de m'avoir corrigé!

Comment: *Une Suisse* is however such a common mistake at least in France that it might eventually become the standard and *Suissesse* outdated/regional. Ex: [Marié avec une Suisse depuis 26 ans, il se rendait quatre fois par an en Turquie où il avait une autre compagne.](http://tempsreel.nouvelobs.com/rue89/rue89-politique/20100802.RUE7821/carte-d-europe-de-la-decheance-de-nationalite.html)